# Removing specific character from Tkinter entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a list of files, and I want to be able to search for their name and open them using the Entry function in Tkinter. The problem is, I need to be able to remove the space character from the Tkinter entry. Here's my code so far:

```
import os
import sys
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

Label(master, text=">").grid(row=0)

name = Entry(master)

name.grid(row=0, column=1)

def openFile():
    os.system("nautilus "+name.get())

Button(master, text='Search', command=openFile).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

I need to take any space entered into the entry bar, out.

I've tried using this method everywhere:

```
for char in ' ': 
    name = name.replace(char,'')
```

But that doesn't work either. I've researched everywhere but could find nothing, presumably due to how specific it is.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you have a string, to remove spaces all you do is `the_string.replace(" ", "")`. What more do you need?

Comment: do you mean `"nautilus "+name.get().replace(" ", "")` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import os
import sys
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

Label(master, text=">").grid(row=0)

x=StringVar()

name = Entry(master,textvariable=x)
name.grid(row=0, column=1)

def openFile():
    y=x.get()
    y.replace(" ","")
    os.system("nautilus "+y)

Button(master, text='Search', command=openFile).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

Hope this helps..